# Изменение title используя jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

У меня есть jQuery функция которая меняет название во всех .task-row классах 
Как я могу изменить локальное место названия Title на место переводов.
С такого

```
 $('.task-row').attr('title', 'Edit');
```

на такой

```
$('.task-row').attr('title', '@Shop.Resources.Properties.Literals.Edit');
```

Comment: на клиенте - никак. `@Shop.Resources.Properties.Literals.Edit` - это ASP.NET Razor?

Comment: `$('.task-row').each(function(){$(this).attr('title', i18n($(this).attr('title'), locale))})`

Comment: @Igor, ну почему никак? Может создать сервис и AJAX'ом подгружать с сервера. Можно при загрузке страницы создать пару переменных и читать уже их

Comment: Спросите как узнать какую именно переменную загружать? `data-` атрибут элемента в помощь )

Comment: @Igor  Да, это Razor.

Comment: Если этот код во View, то он сработает. Если код в js файле, то он, конечно, неправильный, так как js файлы пересылаются отдельным запросом и Razor-ом не обрабатываются.

Comment: Если передать этот текст на клиент вместе со страницей возможности нет, то надо его запрашивать с помощью `$.ajax`.

Comment: @Igor Да, код вынесен в js. С Razor работаю два дня и не знал, что так  не сработает. Спасибо.  Я так понимаю, что по простому из js я это не сделаю?

Comment: Если перевода слова "Edit" к этому моменту на клиенте нет, придется его запрашивать с сервера. Ну и есть варианты с библиотеками, как упомянутый выше @vp_arth `i18n`.

Comment: @Igor может вынесите отдельно ответ и я отмечу его как верный. Если хотите конечно. В любом случае огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как мы выяснили, `@Shop.Resources.Properties.Literals.Edit` - это ASP.NET Razor.

Если этот код во View, то он сработает. Если код в js файле, то он, конечно, неправильный, так как js файлы пересылаются отдельным запросом и Razor-ом не обрабатываются.

Если передать этот текст на клиент вместе со страницей возможности нет, то можно его запрашивать с помощью `$.ajax`.

Еще есть варианты с библиотеками, как упомянутый выше @vp_arth `i18n`.

https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n